# How to setup Xbee without X-CTU(official tool)

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, xbee

I try to make two raspberry pi communicate (text) with each other via XBee S2 module. Instead of using XBee shield, I connected XBee and pi with dupont lines(PIN: 3.3V, Tx, Rx, Ground).

Under pi, install minicom and

```
minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I could enter XBee command mode, where I got reply 'OK' when I type some commands. My test architecture is shown below.

```
(C)PI-XBee      (R)XBee-PI
```

I set same PANID and destination address as source address of each other. However, I cannot get the message from each other in **minicom**.

Did I miss something? Or I did need to setup with X-CTU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you exit command mode before sending data (I think the command is `ATCN`, or just let command mode time out)?  Are the modules joined to the same network?  Check `AI` (association indicator, should be zero), `SC` (scan channels, identical on both modules), `CH` (channel) and `OI` (operating PAN ID).  The read-only `CH` and `OI` should be the same on both modules if they're on the same network.  Use `ATNR` to reset the network on the coordinator, and then on the router to force it to rejoin the network.  Be sure to use `ATWR` to write your settings if you want them to stick after power cycling.

Edit: Turns out both modules had Router firmware installed, so they were both trying to join a network.  The S2B has different firmware files for Coordinator and Router/End Device node types.  The S2C has a single firmware and uses the setting of `ATCE` to select coordinator (1) or router/end device (0) operation.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Both `AI` are `21`, which you mentioned that it should be 0. Other parameters are the same in two XBee. I exit command mode `ATCN` to try to send text to each other. How would I fix it?

Comment: You're sure one is coordinator? Make sure SC is 0x3FFF. On some modules you need to set CE=1 to be coordinator (XBee S2C). Try looking up AI values in docs -- coordinator should be able to establish network and go to AI=0 in almost all cases.

Comment: I didn't know I need to do so. However, after I set SC to 0x3FFF, `AT` value changed to `FF`. Is there any doc for setting via command mode? I do need to check my process step by step.

Comment: Doc for troubleshooting joins: http://ftp1.digi.com/support/images/App_Note__DebuggingJoining.pdf

Comment: Note that coordinator should establish a network quickly, within less than a minute.  You're sure one module has coordinator firmware on it and the other has router firmware on it?  What's the `ATVR` response?  Are these XBee S2B or S2C modules?  The S2C has a single firmware, and you enable coordinator with `ATCE=1`.  The S2B has a coordinator firmware and a separate router/end device firmware.

Comment: ATVR is 22A7. They are S2B modules. How to set ATCE value to 1? `atce` always return `ERROR` msg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102199/discussion-between-user2174595-and-tomlogic).